# Rails destroy controller doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy, railtie

Pretty much there in the title. I worked on a project with someone else, then cloned the git repo to my computer, added a new controller, and then thought better so ran:

```
rails destroy controller requests
```

(requests is the name of the controller), only to get this endless error message:

```
/Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:181:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :controller (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:78:in `normalize_options!'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:61:in `initialize'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1304:in `new'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1304:in `add_route'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1284:in `decomposed_match'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1270:in `block in match'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1270:in `each'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1270:in `match'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:507:in `map_method'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:469:in `get'
    from /Users/sashafklein/rails_projects/meatup/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
    from /Users/sashafklein/rails_projects/meatup/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/sashafklein/rails_projects/meatup/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

It's worked before, so what's happening? Might I need to reinstall something that got overwritten?

Also, any ideas why on earth is the error pasting all that stuff about the rails tutorial I'm taking? I don't remember that text being anywhere in my files?

Thanks

Comment: FYI: Error stack traces usually look like this. As you learn more Rails, you'll find out this is a pretty short one..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you might have an error with your routes. Did any new routes get added to your routes.rb? If so, try commenting them out and then running your command.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work. There were new routes added there when I generated the "requests" controller, but should destroy have rolled them back automatically? (At any rate, I deleted them and tried again, but pretty much the same errors arise).

Comment: What is on line 3 of your config/routes.rb file? It seems like that line is causing an issue

Comment: Yeah. It was an auto-generated requests route, but when I cut it out, the problem doesn't go away. And should "destroy" automatically cut it out?

Comment: WAIT. Second time did it. Sorry to bother you. Thanks so much!